# УОВ ОРТИМИЕ УО ПОСАКА ТРИ БЕРЕКОВЕСЕКЕ

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Найдена берестяная грамота, которую не могут расшифровать. Зализняк предположил, что ПОСАК - вор или мошенник.

https://m.lenta.ru/news/2016/06/23/posak/

Объясните, чем не подходит очевидное "Уов получает (укр. отримує, бел. атрымае) в приданое (укр. посаг, бел. пасаг) три пуда", написанное с грамматическими ошибками.  Такую расшифровку уже несколько дней предлагают разные блогеры.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы объясните, какие именно "грамматические" ошибки тут допущены, как должно это звучать "без ошибок", представите снимок исходного текста и дадите ссылку на Зализняка (скорее всего его опять неверно поняли), обещаю подумать. А так - бред от ленты.ру. Там даже снимок явно не того текста выложен. Просматривается текст "...ОПJСАЕ...ИЕОБ...".  Что тут гадать-то?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]